# How to load pdf in webview from assets folder

Tags: android

I have problem to load pdf from asset folder this code not working for me please help. when i open this location in chrome showing the pdf in app does not showing error="ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME"

```
val web=findViewById<WebView>(R.id.weber)
    val settings = web.getSettings()
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
    settings.builtInZoomControls = true
    web.setWebChromeClient(WebChromeClient())
    web.loadUrl("F:\\Studyfy\\app\\src\\main\\assets\\p.pdf")
```

Comment: You have several problems. First, Android is not Windows. There is no `F:` on Android. Second, `loadUrl()` takes a URL, which includes a scheme. For example, the URL of this Web page is `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57134492/how-to-load-pdf-in-webview-from-assets-folder`. The scheme of this URL is `https`. Third, an asset is not a file on the Android filesystem. Fourth, `WebView` has no built-in ability to view a PDF.

Comment: I blogged a couple of years ago about [options for viewing PDFs](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html) in an Android app.

Comment: sir i have problem with pdf viewer when i implement the 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2' it taking more space please suggest any other pdfviwer to decrease the size

Comment: The simplest solution is to use `ACTION_VIEW` and let the user choose a PDF viewer to use. The next-best solution is to not use PDF, but instead use HTML+CSS and view that directly using a `WebView`. I outlined some other options in [the blog post that I pointed to earlier](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html), though they all have their problems, either in terms of how well they render PDFs or their size.

Comment: You can put the pdf in google drive and create sharing link and can open the pdf using the webview or intent.

Answer (score 1):

1) Enable the below permission in manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

2) Put this code block inside OnCreate method

```
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "sample.pdf");
            try
            {
                in = assetManager.open("sample.pdf");
                out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"+getFilesDir()+"/sample.pdf"),"application/pdf");
            startActivity(intent);
```

3) Put this method inside your class (Outside of OnCreate)

```
 private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
```